# MS Access: Selecting only if count is less than 2

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, a fairly simple set of code that I can't seem to figure out how to work it.  Using the very simple select statement

```
SELECT ref, pos, trans, ticket_number, timestamp
FROM trans
WHERE trans Like "*refund*"
```

Provides the correct response of:

[image]

Now the issue lies in: We only want to count the "Refund started" without the following "Refund cancelled." So this would ONLY return ref 3872 & 7555.  The extra issue is if the person starts an actual legitimate refund on the same ticket(Started, cancelled, started) and count that as a legit refund.  I have tried a group by, but for some reason it will not pull the group.  It gives the error of:
[image]

when I give it:

```
SELECT ref, pos, trans, ticket_number, timestamp
FROM trans
WHERE trans Like "*refund*"
group by ticket_number
```

or

```
SELECT trans.ref, trans.pos, trans.trans, trans.ticket_number, trans.timestamp, Count(trans.ticket_number) AS CountOfticket_number
FROM trans
WHERE (((trans.[trans]) Like "*refund*"))
GROUP BY trans.ticket_number;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like @Gordon Linoff's answer, but to offer an alternative, here is another way to approach it using joins:

```sql
select t.ref, t.pos, t.trans, t.ticket_number, t.timestamp
from trans t inner join
(
    select t.ticket_number
    from trans t
    group by t.ticket_number
    having sum((t.trans = 'Refund started.')-(t.trans = 'Refund cancelled.'))<>0
) t1 
on t1.ticket_number = t.ticket_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want tickets that have more starts than cancels.  If so:

```
SELECT ref, pos, trans, ticket_number, timestamp
FROM trans
WHERE ticket_number IN (SELECT ticket_number
                        FROM trans
                        GROUP BY ticket_number
                        HAVING SUM(SWITCH(trans = "Refund started", 1,
                                          trans = "Refund cancelled", -1
                                          1=1, 0
                                         )
                                  ) > 0
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could obatin the ticket_number with a single trans value  using a subquery for count = 1

```
SELECT ref, pos, trans, ticket_number, timestamp
FROM trans where ticket_number IN  (
select ticket_number 
from (
  select distinct ticket_number, trans 
  from trans

) 
group by ticket_number
having count(*) = 1 )
```

Comment: That wields 0 results.